# What API is there for querying the current focus name in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, macos

I have developed a task management application that I'd like to use the current focus to filter which tasks are displayed to the user, via an apple API.  At the moment, I'm just working on implementing my own, but it seems a waste to duplicate if there is an API out there.  The only API I've been able to find appears to just tell you if your app is in focus, not the name of the current focus.

**Is there an API for querying the current focus name in iOS?**

Comment: I can only find a boolean `isFocused` for it https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/infocusstatus. This might be helpful: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appintents/focus/defining_your_app_s_focus_filter

Comment: I'd seen the first link -- hadn't seen the 2nd one, thanks for that.  It certainly doesn't appear there is one right now -- hopefully someone else will have some idea about an upcoming API :)

Comment: Do not include an answer / solution in the Question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out that apple does have an API built in that will allow you to effectively be notified of focus changes, provided the end user configures it.

Here is a link to the WWDC video outlining it: [WWDC](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/10121/)

Sample code implementing a basic focus filter:

```
struct AppFocusFilter: SetFocusFilterIntent {
  static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "Use focus in your app"
  static var description: LocalizedStringResource = "Set the focus name to match this focus."
  @Parameter(title: "Focus Name") var focusName: String

  var displayRepresentation: DisplayRepresentation {
    DisplayRepresentation(title: "use focus: \(focusName)", subtitle: "for something in app")
  }

  func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult {
    print("this gets called with \(self.focusName) set when the focus changes while the app is active")
    // to check the focus when the app becomes active, use:
    // try await AppFocusFilter.current.focusName
    return .result()
  }
}
```

In order for this code to get called, the end-user must go into their focus settings -- for every focus they want the app to know about, and scroll down and click "Add Filter".  Once that is set up, the filter name they enter will be set on the AppFocusFilter.current object whenever the focus changes (and the perform() method above will be called if the app is the active application).

Thanks very much to [@Alexander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3141234/alexander) for your pointer to the full documentation, which I hadn't found before.